# Reputation decreased because of downvote without actual downvote

Tags: support, reputation-history

This is my first post in here so please excuse me for any lack of knowledge, but here's a problem I'm facing :

I got a -2 reputation change yesterday and my profile says it's because of a downvote. Here's a screenshot :
[image: -2 Reputation because of downvote]

But when I go the specified link, the answer which was downvoted, there is no downvote :
[image: NO downvotes shown]

This whole thing happened yesterday and so I waited for a complete day in case it was a syncing issue. Now that I'm sure it's not that, can anyone please clarify the reason behind this event?

Comment: Do you realize that score = upvotes-downvotes?

Comment: 1 upvote - 1 downvote = 0

Comment: @Rizier123 exactly

Comment: Oh, that explains it. Thanks for clarification. I wish for every answer written, upvotes and downvotes to be shown separately only for the author. That will definitely help :)

Comment: @gonephishing The reason for upvotes and downvotes not showing seperately are, I believe, security reasons, as I read in reddit's FAQ.

Comment: @Filipkovarik: no, there is a *performance* reason. Users with 1000 reputation can see the breakdown, but as the score is stored denormalised that requires extra database queries, so this functionality is limited to a more dedicated subset of all users.

Comment: Didn't realize we host the FAQ on reddit....

Comment: @rene -_- note the "I believe", if he wants his answer quick, It'll at least make **some** sense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  The question was about losing 2 reputation point. I ended up losing 10. That's highly encouraging for a first time user here.

Comment: @gonephishing: I'm sorry you did; posting on Meta means you get more attention towards a post. More attention can lead to more voting, and in this case that didn't work out so well for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You got an upvote on that answer on June 30th, and a downvote yesterday. So the answer score is 0, and your reputation gain from it is +8 (10 for the upvote, -2 for the downvote).

You can view the vote splits on any question once you earn the [Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege (1000 rep).

As an aside: please don't use textspeak in your posts on Stack Exchange, take the time to spell them properly.

Comment: Not sure why you made this CW; there is no reputation on Meta to gain or lose anyway, and this isn't a [tag:faq] page. :-)

Comment: Bah, was essentially summing up comments, so felt like ticking that checkbox. (Interestingly you get a warning telling you you'll gain no rep from the post even here on meta.)

Comment: Thanks Mat for helping :) Hey @MartijnPieters, we don't gain/lose reputation for answering on SO-Meta but we lose reputation for asking. Wow :)

Comment: @gonephishing: no, you don't. There's no rep on site metas. (Only Meta Stack Exchange has rep, that's a site of its own.)

Comment: @Mat: I think gonephishing suffered from the Meta effect; this question here may have drawn attention to their posts leading to more votes on the main site. Although such attention can go both ways, it looks like the answer attracted a few more downvotes because of that attention.